# z/OS TSO STACK MACRO to specify alternate DDnames

Tags: macros, stack, zos, tso

I am trying to use the STACK macro ( http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.ikjb700/lfosmi.htm ) to specify an alternate DDname for SYSTSPRT, but I can't get it to work. Has anyone ever had success with STACK DATASET? I couldn't find any documentation on how to use it. When I try, the call succeeds, but the output still gets written to SYSTSPRT

thanks, mike

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Would you add the attempt you have so far to the question please?

Comment: @Don Cruickshank Not sure how I append my code - there seems to be a very small character limit...

Comment: The sequence I am doing is to call IKJTSOEV, make sure it's ok, then use the UPT/ECT/ECB from the CPPL that I get back from IKJTSOEV to call STACK with DATASET=OUTDD=OUT, then check the return codes. 'OUT' has RDSYSPRT in it. Finally, I call IKJEFTSR to do a simple command. At this point, I am just doing an 'ALTLIB DISPLAY'. With that sequence, the results are still being written to SYSTSPRT.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would say is to believe that IBM code works, as documented, unless you have solid evidence otherwise.

I have just read the IBM documentation you linked to.  It states that you need to pre-allocate the dataset being referenced by the STACK macro.

Have you done this?  Your brief explanation does NOT mention what you want allocated to SYSTSPRT??

Comment: Yes - I pre-allocated the DDName with JCL, e.g. //SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*
I am now pursuing alternatives since this doesn't seem to be a path others are taking - in particular, I am using the ISPF gateway and the new CEA TSO approaches. Both have their weaknesses, but there seems to be support for those interfaces.

Comment: I think the SYSOUT=* means to use the terminal/printer?  Try allocating to a physical dataset?